# How to change concurrencyMode Apex batch

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

The documentation ([Unable to lock row - Record currently unavailable errors](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000229525&type=1)
) says to change '**concurrencyMode**' to Serial instead of Parallel.

But I can't find how to change this property in apex batch or apex scheduled job.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

`concurrencyMode` does not pertain to batch or scheduled Apex. It is specific to the Bulk API, used for large-volume data loads.

Row-locking errors in batch and other forms of Asynchronous Apex typically do not have so simple a solution. They are highly case-specific, and always stem from a situation in which multiple concurrent processes (including user interaction) seek exclusive access to a record or a parent of a record.

The [Record Locking Cheat Sheet](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/07/record-locking-cheat-sheet.html) is a good first stop to identify the causes of the contending locks. Then, next steps would have to do with ensuring that processes contending for locks on the same records are serialized or use exclusion logic to ignore one another's scopes.

However, if the row locking is a rare error, retry logic is likely to be the solution rather than a major refactoring.